# Laptop running on house inverter adds flickering to lights, was wondering if a capacitor can help

Tags: inverter, ups

I recently installed a pure sine wave inverter system ([Exide GQP 24V 1450VA](https://www.exideindustries.com/products/home-ups-system/exide-inverterz-gqp.aspx)) capable of delivering a 1000 watts to combat frequent power cuts.

The inverter is wired at the mains input of the house and all the appliances like fans and tubelights, wall sockets can run on the inverter. Heavy appliances like refrigerators, microwave etc have different supply and are not wired through the inverter.

I have a Lenovo Legion Y540 gaming laptop which I use for my software development job.
The power brick is rated for 170 Watts max.

The issue:

Whenever the inverter is supplying power and my laptop is powered on, the LED tube lights flicker. It continuously happens and is almost noticeable. I can also see the flicker increasing and reducing proportionally based on the workload on the laptop.
If I put the laptop on sleep, the flickering stops. If I disconnect the laptop power supply the flickering stops.

A single brief flicker also happens when an inductive load such as a fan is started, which is expected when a motor starts.

I am just running two tube lights of 15 watts each with the laptop so its not like the inverter is near its max load.

I don't really understand why and how would a laptop put so much varying load on the electrical system that the inverter with such a capacity is unable to cope up.

We have a utility supply of 230-245 Volts AC. The inverter provides consistent 220V AC output.

I was wondering if placing a capacitor across the supply might help as it looks like the laptop is demanding power in bursts which the inverter is not able to cope up with. If yes, I don't really know what rating should the capacitor be.

Comment: I'm just a little bit worried about the wiring in your house and your use of that wiring.

Comment: @jonk, any specific reason for that? Everything works perfectly fine when the power is supplied from the grid, which again passes through the inverter wiring. Its just the laptop causing the issue only when the inverter is supplying power.

Comment: Only your writing. What you describe sounds like poor wiring (insufficient wire cross-section) and/or over-use/abuse of the wiring. Or else it sounds as though you live in India. (Which now that I'm looking at the inverter... )

Comment: @jonk, Yes I do live in india, but my point is, even if the wiring is not good enough, the same wiring and supply path is being used for the grid supply and inverter supply. So I was wondering what's the difference and what I can do to fix it. I just feel that the laptop is demanding power in bursts and the inverter is not capable enough to handle those bursts.

Comment: Inexpensive LED light bulbs tend to be extremely sensitive to fluctuations in supply voltage. When you're running off the inverter, the switched modes supply in your laptop generates sudden pulses of load current which cause the supply voltage to drop until the inverter can respond. You see these as flicker. This isn't something you can correct short of redesigning the lights or the inverter.

Comment: @user1850479, thank you, your comment confirms my doubt that the laptop/power brick is the culprit, puts me at peace.

Comment: The laptop is the culprit, but the LED's  differential sensitivity to peak voltage makes it blink lower, then overshoot at a 25 Hz modulation rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal EMI from flyback pulse noises created by the lousy filter in the laptop charger and the poor susceptibility of AC LED luminaires. You can improve it with a high quality and expensive line filter or make your own for much less.

### Anecdotal info

My TV room dimmable MR30 LEDs by Philips blink whenever the bathroom fan shuts off. I fixed that with a 1 nF metal film cap across the fan switch.

Now,  in the kitchen I am the only one who notices the same effect in the same TV room LEDs blink, everytime the Sunbeam coffee pot heater shuts off with its bimetallic thermal switch, most times when I hear a quiet click from the kitchen.  The next time I see a suitable metal film cap of 1 nF, that's where it goes, across the bimetallic switch.

But in your case it switches with the buck regulator and there is probably a differential and common mode line LC filter, but it is inadequate for your higher impedance of your UPS and LED combination.

It's impossible to avoid some flyback EMF as the power lines do have almost 1 uH per meter but when paired weakly some of that cancels. So the net loop area becomes an antenna and the common mode noise to ground may also radiate depending on how well it is connected to protective earth (PE).  This may conduct the noise like a daisy chain right past the LEDs or not. There may be other radiated or conductive paths I can't see.

But it is definitely a marginally-poor power supply, as your tower PSU might not do such a thing. PC PSU's  tend to be **better, designed with forward converters and active PFC now,** **rather than flyback** which are cheaper to make yet only suitable for 100W or so.

But if you want to just try a 1nF cap across the outlet with a dummy plug in the duplex outlet or open up the charger. That's the weakest fix, but it's worth a try.  You may be able to use slightly more or less, but it won't harm anything, as the charger already has Y caps on the CM choke filter to protective earth. You may need a better DM or CM choke to improve the susceptibility in the bandwidth range that is affected, which would be included in a high-quality line filter.

Let's hope India gets around to improving its power infrastructure. Our power almost never goes out. … Except for that ice storm a few years ago and part of old Toronto got hit and the odd blip with ice thaw on buried cable in spring from moisture creapage. Oh! And by the way, all those line conditioners you guys use? That's part of the instability problem. A drop in grid with a conditioner response by all demands a tap change to increase the residence voltage also demands more current and further drops the grid. Until it faults out. But that's a secondary, not the primary cause.

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed response, I really appreciate it. And about the power infra here, it's very good in some cities where the power company is privately owned. At other places the government is simply too lazy to upgrade their infra as per the increasing load demands. people are installing ACs, Microwaves, water and room heaters but the utility lines remain the same as 10 years back, causes the HT wires and fuses to burn.

Comment: can that also happen if you don't have any earthing in the house?